# Using parallel_sort algorithm on a struct

Tags: c++, sorting

How to use [parallel_sort](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/tbb_sa/help/reference/algorithms/parallel_sort_func.htm) with this struct:

```
struct d
{
    char name[5];
};

struct less_than_key
{
    inline bool operator() (const d& struct1, const d& struct2) const
    {
        return strcmp(struct1.name, struct2.name) == -1;
    }
};

vector<d> my_d;
my_d.resize(3);

strcpy(my_d[0].name, "mike");
strcpy(my_d[1].name, "joe");
strcpy(my_d[2].name, "anna");

parallel_sort(my_d.begin(), my_d.end(), less_than_key());
```

**DONE!**, I hope this helps someone else.

Guess it's time to take my Phd in sorting algorithms!

Comment: The error is clearly visible. Go check the interface of vector, and if you still don't have a clue, consider following the advice in my first comment.

Comment: I'm still going to tell you to use std::string instead of char arrays. It makes code initialisations like these so much safer and more elegant.

Comment: `std::vector<memory_data>::iterator it;` `parallel_sort(z, it + items);`

Comment: @polkadotcadaver: i see your point, i will seriously consider it...

Comment: did the code above made any progress (but still doesn't work...)

Comment: (http://stackoverflow.com/a/5294249/1018966) follow this...

Comment: Your struct needs an `operator<` that implements strict weak ordering.  Assuming you do that then `parallel_sort(my_d.begin(), my_d.end());` should work.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to implement that operator?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380463/sorting-a-vector-of-custom-objects

Comment: You do realize your sort is comparing the address of the literal strings in memory and not the content of the strings themselves right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use C-style strings when you can easily use `std::string`.

Since your struct only contains a string you may want to just use `std::string` instead (which implements the operators that you need for `parallel_sort` to work).

```
std::vector<std::string> vec(3);
vec.emplace_back("mike");
vec.emplace_back("joe");
vec.emplace_back("anna");
```

and then, following the function signature, you just need to find the begin and end iterator:

```
parallel_sort(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec));
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the suggestion, but can you help me do it with chars, please?

Comment: I tried and made my code almost correct

Comment: @SkyRipper, why do you want it with chars?

Comment: For performance reasons(I know it's very little, but the little counts and I have many data)

Comment: Based on how hard it was for you to figure out how this works at all I feel like you didn't profile both solutions to see which was faster and just assume, most likely incorrectly, that bare character arrays are faster.